# Selecting on another table if a table does not exist

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite, how do I select on another table if a table does not exist? I want to do something like the following in one query:

```
if not exists(tbl_lite){
    select * from tbl_heavy
} else {
    select * from tbl_lite
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you need to first check if table exists using this query and do select from appropriate table

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='tbl_lite'
```

Comment: Could there be no single query for the question?

Comment: @b16db0 , i tried this, it works only if table exists SELECT *
FROM tbl_lite
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='tbl_lite')

Comment: Could you include the tbl_heavy?

Comment: @b16db0, SELECT *
FROM tbl_lite
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='tbl_lite')
UNION
SELECT *
FROM tbl_heavy
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='tbl_heavy')
AND EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='tbl_heavy')
this query expects both tables to be present other wise gives syntax error but gets data from tbl_list if exists.